# Ошибка в блокноте google collab при запуске wizardcoder-13b/mistral-7b на python

Tags: python, сервер, искусственный-интеллект, google-colaboratory, python-openai

Есть два блокнота google colabalatory в каждом запускается ИИ чат бот - в одном mistral-7b, а в другом wizardcoder. Кроме localhost и public URL код выдавал нужную мне ссылку формата openAi.Всё работало, но вчера я перезапустил оба блокнота и они начали выдавать ошибку 404 на последней ячейке запуска этих ботов.
[image: ошибка1]
Я потратил на это весь день, а в итоге ошибка сама, без каких-либо изменений в коде - поменялась! Теперь же localhost и public url появляются и работают, а за место нужной мне openai ссылки лишь ошибка

```
    Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
Running on public URL: https://f183763a4bf5eebdd5.gradio.live

This share link expires in 72 hours. For free permanent hosting and GPU upgrades, run `gradio deploy` from Terminal to deploy to Spaces (https://huggingface.co/spaces)
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_server):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/content/text-generation-webui/extensions/openai/script.py", line 338, in run_server
    public_url = _run_cloudflared(port, port + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_cloudflared.py", line 137, in _run_cloudflared
    raise Exception(f"! Can't connect to Cloudflare Edge")
Exception: ! Can't connect to Cloudflare Edge
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/text-generation-webui/extensions/api/util.py", line 112, in _start_cloudflared
    public_url = _run_cloudflared(port, port + 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask_cloudflared.py", line 137, in _run_cloudflared
    raise Exception(f"! Can't connect to Cloudflare Edge")
Exception: ! Can't connect to Cloudflare Edge
Exception in thread Thread-5 (_start_cloudflared):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1016, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 953, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/content/text-generation-webui/extensions/api/util.py", line 122, in _start_cloudflared
    raise Exception('Could not start cloudflared.')
Exception: Could not start cloudflared.
```

Изначально блокноты были не мои, а я их нашел на просторах интеренета. Я лишь отредактировал внешний вид, пару ошибок и переходы между папок. У человека у которого я их взял все до сих пор работает (после моих правок все работало!).

- мои блокноты:
  mistral-7b: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sHIU1-QxKvMVz_SoI-JtqqK1TVotxMq_?usp=sharing#scrollTo=JWYNl8wBVpw1 
  wizardcoder: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/15jkIVBbkDDYd3FheAJOy8oKoSI558Wf4?usp=sharing&pli=1&authuser=1#scrollTo=kPmAGXt0Z-SI
- блокноты автора:
  wizardcoder: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1gJm42ADyyr-4B5i8BpfhA-_va4h_Pohd?usp=sharing 
  mistral-7b: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1mhi79GfQREbq6YN1guzeB-Pw0V3XxoTJ?usp=sharing

Весь код там на python, пожалуйста помогите исправить ошибку при запуске последней ячейки в обоих блокнотах.

Comment: Пожалуйста отправляйте код и ошибки в виде текста, а не скриншота

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей почему?

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей ошибки 404 у меня уже нет в виде текста, а вот крайняя ошибка есть в блокноте + на скриншоте, она очень большая и не думаю, что влезет сюда или будет удобна тут в прочтении

Comment: 1) Код/текст ошибки можно копировать и использовать в ответе
2) Нет необходимости в открытии и приближении к скриншоту

Comment: Вы можете использовать блоки кода что бы ошибка не занимала слишком много места

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей ошибки сохранены в моих коллабах, ссылку на которые я оставил в конце

Comment: В будущем эти ссылки могут стать недействительными, и другие люди со схожей проблемой не смогут воспользоваться вашим ответом. Позвольте мне отредактировать вопрос...

Comment: + я не могу видеть ваши ошибки в блокнотах

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей тогда спасибо за комментарий. Сейчас отредактирую!

Comment: @ШвеевАлексей почему-то я думал, что ошибка в разы больше XD