# Ошибка запуска LLMs (wizardcoder-13b) в google colabolatory

Tags: python, сервер, искусственный-интеллект, google-colaboratory, python-openai

На прошлые два вопроса по данной тематике мне так никто и не ответил, но и они чудесным образом решились ([Вопрос №1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549671/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-llms-autogen-%D0%B2-google-collab-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python), [вопрос №2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1549346/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-google-collab-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)). Я пытаюсь запустить в google colab wizardcoder-13b и mistral-7b, но так чтобы получить API ключ формата chatGPT чтобы воспользоваться им как на этом [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GM5EPdy3p-o&t=13s). Но мои попытки не увенчались успехом, почти каждая новая генерация - это новая ошибка. Сейчас стараюсь запустить хотя бы wizardcoder чтобы он работал через API, но вот что происходит.

1. у автора видео все запускается как есть и не нужны дополнительные манипуляции с google colab (кроме как создания папки wizarcoder-13b в models/), но у меня запуск сервера сразу написал в терминал, что нету модуля "flask_cloudflared" - пришлось устанавливать. (!pip install flask_cloudflared)
2. после установки библиотеки терминал выводит все чисто и в конце мы видим:

```
2023-11-16 10:45:23 INFO:Loaded the model in 49.89 seconds.
2023-11-16 10:45:23 INFO:Loading the extension "openai"...
2023-11-16 10:45:23 INFO:Loading the extension "gallery"...
 * Downloading cloudflared for Linux x86_64...
Running on local URL:  http://127.0.0.1:7860
2023-11-16 10:45:28 INFO:OpenAI compatible API URL:

https://parameters-measurement-fat-venues.trycloudflare.com

INFO:     Started server process [4940]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:5000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
Running on public URL: https://795071272280c83a8a.gradio.live
```

но если перейти по нужной мне сгенерированной API ссылке, то там мы увидим:

```
{
    "detail": "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

а уже в терминале появится это:

```
INFO:     188.234.93.15:0 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 405 Method Not Allowed
```

P.S. если перейти по public URL, то там будем рабочий wizardcoder с стандартным интерфейсом gradio, но проблема в том что эта ссылка не формата openAI API и при её использовании в autogen будет ошибка, но также люди спокойно указывают в конфиге autogen не API ключ, а local URL и все работает (это работает в случае pro аккаунта в google colaboratory, ведь тогда нету таких ограничений по сеансам и мощностям(в нашем случае можно ток один сеанс на один аккаунт) или при запуске локально через LMstudio, но у нас нет таких мощностей чтобы запускать несколько нейросетей локально). Если бы можно было использовать public URL, то это было бы просто отлично так как он не работает лишь в очень редких случаях.